Calculate Hurst exponent for log stock time series
I try to calculate the Hurst exponent for the main stock time series. When I applied classical R/S analysis (Matlab code developed by Weron) I received the same value of Theoretical Hurst exponent for all series.
Is it appropriate to use log data for R/S analysis and calculation of the Hurst exponent? Or is there a problem with the stock series and we have to use the Generalised Hurst Exponent?
